# When is it safe to consider realm db file as closed and back it up safely

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am using a realm in android and need to backup db file. That is easy and mentioned a lot of times, but I can not find out when can I consider realm db file as closed, so that file will be 100% OK without any write in progress or pending update.

Is it imediately after realm.close() is called ?

Answer (score 1):

When `Realm.getGlobalInstanceCount(realmConfiguration)` return 0.

However, Realm doesn't need to be closed if you use `realm.writeCopyTo()`, so you should probably use that.